# How to fill an .obj and stich edges together?

Tags: mesh, objects

I recently Created a 3D model with sculptris using sheets indead of the solid sphere normally provided (in hindsight not the best idea) but a lot of the edges don't touch leaving gaps in the mesh and the model is hollow. i was wondering if there is any way to "stitch" the edges together and make the object solid?

Thank you. 
[image: problem area]
[image: whole model]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to "stitch" the open gaps together, try going into edit mode, selecting some vertices you want to stitch and press "F", which will connect the vertices together and create a face. Mess around with that for awhile and you should get the hang of it.

Comment: Ahh okay that makes more sense, Thank you ^w^